# Llamar a un método sin que sea necesario asignar una variable del objeto

Tags: c#

Tengo esta clase:

```
class Prueba
{
    public void f1(){}
}
```

Y quiero llamar al método **`f1()`** solamente una vez.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

- Así:

  ```
  Prueba p = new Prueba();
  p.f1();
  //resto de código
  ```
- O así:

  ```
  new Prueba().f1();
  //resto de código
  ```

Comment: El segundo es el mas conveniente ya que solo lo usarías una vez.

Comment: Es cuestión de gusto personal.

Comment: Te da igual cual utilizar

Comment: Yo creo que si no hay necesidad de usar una instancia debería ser una función estática. ¿Crearías una instancia solo para llamar a la función `f1`?

Answer (score 3):

En cuanto a tu pregunta, es pura cuestión de gustos. Ambas formas representan lo mismo (con o sin una variable que queda referenciando al objeto). Sin embargo, quizás te conviene pensarlo de otra forma:

No es necesario instanciar un método cuando es un [**método estático**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

```
class Prueba
{
    public static void f1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Me llamaron sin usar new!!!");
    }
}
```

```
Prueba.f1();
```

---

Los métodos definidos con [**`static`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) son invocables sin crear instancias de la clase.

- Se invoca con el nombre de la clase, no del objeto que se instanció (sin usar `new`).
- Se crea una única copia, y no una por cada objeto.
- Pero no tienen acceso a las propiedades o eventos no estáticos de la clase (porque se invocan desde un objeto instanciado).

Otra opción es definir a la clase como `static` (no a sus métodos), haciendo que toda la clase no sea instanciable, pero que todos sus miembros sean estáticos.